# Why isn't localStorage persisting in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm trying to learn how to use the localStorage js object with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveStuff() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('sessionKey', 'sessionValue');
    localStorage.setItem('localKey', 'localValue');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="saveStuff()">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware this doesn't always work with file:/// so I'm using mongoose to serve it up. When I click the save button, the results look correct to me in Chrome's JavaScript console. However when I press refresh both the local and the session storage get cleared where I was expecting the local storage value to persist. This happens on both `http://127.0.0.1/` and `http://localhost/`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? In Settings, Content Settings I have selected 'Allow local data to be set (recommended)' and unticked 'Block third-party cookies and site data'. Am I missing something in my code?

(Chrome Version 23.0.1271.64 m)

Comment: Does this fiddle work? http://jsfiddle.net/6bvjD/ When you click "save" and then reload the page, I do obtain the stored values.

Comment: Well wtf. Yes it does. Which implies in order for saved values to persist there must be an attempt at reading it? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're not in any way calling `localStorage.clear()` or `localStorage.removeItem`?

Comment: 100%. Using the exact page in my answer below produces the behaviour I expected: when I reload the page both variables are still there, and when I close and reopen only local is still there. Bizzaro @ chrome, but thanks for your help!

Comment: I can confirm the issue on chrome 42.0.2311.135 m. localstorage.getItem("X") before setItem("X","V") allow to retrieve the value after killing all chrome process. In case of a setItem("X","V") occurs before  a getItem("X") works as long as you do not kill all chrome processes: After all chrome processes killed the localstorage key "X" is lost..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok. Thanks must go to pimvdb on this one but here's the solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveStuff() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('sessionKey', 'sessionValue');
    localStorage.setItem('localKey', 'localValue');
}
localStorage.getItem('localKey');
sessionStorage.getItem('sessionKey');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="saveStuff()">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Summary seems to be that that you must attempt a read of the key in order to persist it.

Conclusion: WTF.

Comment: I assume this is a bug. Raised [#160056](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160056).

Comment: This looks like a bug in DevTools. The storage entry is not shown in the Resources panel until you actually access `localStorage` or any property. If you just execute `localStorage;` at page load then DevTools works fine.

Comment: I am showing the value in the console.log, but it still not persisting. (Chrome)

Comment: I dealt with this kind of problem and I managed to clean it up, but I do not know if the approach I used is correct.
That is, I discovered that in the Chrome browser settings and in the Advanced section there was the solution.
Within this section, there is the one that deals with Content Settings and, more deeply, in the Cookies section, there is the item 'Keep local data only until you exit the browser' (or something similar).
In 'Permit', I commanded 'Add' and I inserted 'localhost', since I am doing tests in local environment. From this action, the persistence of the data met API rules.

Answer (score 12):

`<!-- Necro post I know, but maybe it helps someone else -->`

I couldn't figure out why I couldn't see something in my `localStorage` in Dev Tools, but could see it in the console when typing `localStorage`. Well, if you store something with Dev Tools open, you won't see `Application -> Local Storage` have anything listed for your host. When I closed/reopened Dev Tools, I could see my data.

So, in conclusion, close/reopen Dev Tools.

Comment: Been pulling my hair out for the last 3 hours trying to figure this out. Your solution worked. Thank you.