# Browser clearing cache on Redirection

Tags: local-storage, payment-gateway, browser-cache, http-redirect, alipay

Cache in local storage of browsers gets cleared when website page redirects from `AliPay` payment website. This is happening in some computers and working fine in some.

From my website user selects `AliPay` payment method then user is redirected to payment website and on successful payment is being redirected back to our website.

In most cases it dont clear cache and works normal but in some cases it clears cache. Why is this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: After some investigating i thought Rapport is making trouble but it is not. This problem is only on chrome but working normally on Mozilla FireFox and internet explorer.

Update 2: After i changed my internet from office to home it started working normally. Internet has any link with chrome which clears cache??

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cache in local storage? What makes you think that it is being cleared?

Comment: JWT token was stored in local storage and after redirection it got cleared. Because of no token my website logged out the user.

Comment: Try to read `localStorage` JWT entry before saving it. Check [Why isn't localStorage persisting in Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292744/why-isnt-localstorage-persisting-in-chrome) question for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of days ago I was also facing this issue the problem was URL.
When I was storing data in localStorage URL was (www.example.com)
but when my visitor redirected from Geoswift he was redirected to URL (example.com) since localStorage largely depends upon URL so that was the problem. which worked for me. I hope this work for you as well :).
Have a great day (y).

Comment: It will be honour if you write a article on this i will post it to my website https://www.codingular.com/

Comment: you're a life saver! Cheers!