# Chrome deletes the localstorage after closing the tab Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, jwt, local-storage

I am developing a web app with Vuejs, and i am using localstorage to store the jwt token , but after i close the tab I found that the token is lost and I need to login again .
i tested the app on Opera GX and it is working just fine, i am having the issue only in Google Chrome.

This is how i set the token :

```
localStorage.setItem("token", token);
```

and this is how i load it :

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
```

Comment: Related stackoverflow issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292744/why-isnt-localstorage-persisting-in-chrome

Related Chrome bug report - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160056

Comment: If that token is confidential, you might as well consider the risk of XSS - https://academind.com/tutorials/localstorage-vs-cookies-xss

Comment: Thanks @Corey The link was very helpful

Comment: Thanks, @Anakin for mentioning the XSS attack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is from Chrome ,

you need to `localstorage.getItem("X")` befor you `setItem("X","V")`

and now the localstorage is persist , even after closing the browser .

this link helped me: [Why isn't localStorage persisting in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292744/why-isnt-localstorage-persisting-in-chrome)

Comment: Is this the only edit that fixed the problem? The issue you refer to is old, I'd expect it to not be applicable to modern Chrome versions.

Comment: That edit solved the issue for me , i am on Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45